# Sending a message from PHP to Python through a socket

Tags: php, python, sockets

I'm trying to send a message to a Python socket using PHP and that it prints the message.

Here is the PHP code so far:

```
<?
$host = "localhost";
$port = 12345;

$f = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($f, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 500000));
$s = socket_connect($f, $host, $port);

$msg = "message";
$len = strlen($msg);

socket_sendto($f, $msg, $len, 0, $host, $port);

socket_close($f);
?>
```

And here is the Python one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "localhost"
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print s.recv(1024)
   c.close()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 15, in <module>
    print s.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I've also tried with `socket_​sendmsg`, `socket_​write`, `fwrite` and many more, but the error in Python is always the same, `socket.error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`.

It looks like I'm really lost.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with sockets, but could the problem be that you're closing it with c.close() so that it can no longer listen to it after the loop goes through once?

Comment: @James I removed it and I still get the error. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: If it doesn't fix the error, you may want to keep it in there. (Sorry I'm no help at all here!)

Comment: @James No problem, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "localhost"
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   data = c.recv(1024)
   if data: print data
   c.close()
```

The main problem is your code was calling `s.recv()` when it should have been on `c.recv()`. Also make sure you check the data received (is it `None`?) before printing.