# Sending result of mysql select query from php to python through a tcp socket

Tags: php, html, mysql, python-3.x, websocket

I'm trying to send the result of my MYSQL select query to my Rpi server using PHP through the TCP socket.

**Here is the PHP code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "fyp_lora";

$host = "localhost";
$port = 12345;

$f = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($f, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' 
=> 500000));
$s = socket_connect($f, $host, $port);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM led_control";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = array();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $data[] = $row;
        echo $row["ID"]. ",". $row["LED"]. "," . $row["Status"] . "<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
foreach($data as $value)
{
$msg= $value["ID"]. ",". $value["LED"]. "," . $value["Status"] . "<br>";
$len = strlen($msg);
while (true) {
        print($msg);
        $sent = socket_write($f, $msg, $len);

        if ($sent === false) {

            break;
        }

        // Check if the entire message has been sent
        if ($sent < $len) {

            // If not send the entire message.
            // Get the part of the message that has not yet been sent as message
        $msg = substr($msg, $sent);

        // Get the length of the not sent part
        $len -= $sent;

    } else {
        socket_close($f);
        break;
    }

}
}
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the python code as referenced by:**
[Sending a message from PHP to Python through a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005774/sending-a-message-from-php-to-python-through-a-socket)

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "localhost"
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5) #allows for 5 connections to be established
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if data: print (str(data.decode().split(",")))
    c.close() #closes the socket
```

On the Rpi server, it will only receive the 1st row of the message for example: **['1', 'LED 1', 'OFF']** but it does not receive the rest of the message.

The full message would be as follows:

1,LED 1,OFF

2,LED 2,OFF

3,LED 3,OFF

4,LED 4,ON

I would greatly appreciate any help given :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason only your first line is being received is because you are calling `socket_close()` after each line is sent in your loop to write data to the socket. This means that the socket is no longer available to `socket_write()` for subsequent passes of the loop for the remaining lines.

Given that you're just running this on your Raspberry Pi, you could do the following as a quick and dirty fix:

```php
foreach ($data as $value) {
  $msg= $value["ID"]. ",". $value["LED"]. "," . $value["Status"] . "\n";
  $len = strlen($msg);
  $connected = socket_connect($f, $host, $port);

  if ($connected) {
    while (true) {
      $sent = socket_write($f, $msg, $len);

      if ($sent === false) {
        break;
      }

      if ($sent < $len) {
        $msg = substr($msg, $sent);
        $len -= $sent;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }

    socket_close($f);
  }
}
```